# Check validation and pass value from edit text to move activity

Tags: java, android

I have a `LoginActivity` that is not tied to any online database, I only validate the username via edit text component to login and move to the `MainActivity`. `LoginActivity` appears when the value of text in `MainActivity` is null, therefore I created a validation method when the username is null, then the layout will move to `LoginActivity`, I made it like this with the aim that `LoginActivity` does not become the main layout of the app.

Validation users in `MainActivity.java`:

```
    private void checkUsername() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getExtras() != null){
        String users = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_USER);
        txuser.setText(users);
        //NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String)
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Contract.UserEntry.NAME_COLUMN,users);
        database.insert(Contract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}
```

`LoginActivity.java`

```
private void loginUser() {
    final String username;
    username = user.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Name cannot be blank!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (!cbAgree.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login fails!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    fabLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UtamaActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USER, username);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I fix this?, because when I open the app for the first time, the `LoginActivity` is successfully displayed, but when I enter to `MainActivity` it immediately forces close. I have included the logcat comment in the `checkUsername()` method

Comment: What is your doubt/question?

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Check whether the database variable is initialised or not before checkUsername runs.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UtamaActivity.class);`
to `Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);`

Comment: the class name of the main activity in my app is `UtamaActivity.java`, no problem in that